# Why is it required for abstract classes to implement named interfaces completly?

Tags: typescript, typescript2.0

Given I have this interface:

```
export class interface State {
  default(): void;
}
```

And this abstract class:

```
export abstract class BaseState implements State {}
```

The typescript compiler tells me that "BaseState incorrectly implements interface State" - but this doesn't make sense to me. If an abstract class implements an interface, it shouldn't be forced to implement all methods of it, since this could also be delegated to subclasses.

I know I can do

```
export abstract class BaseState implements State {
  abstract default(): void;
}
```

but this definitely isn't DRY. So, is there any good reason to have this behaviour in TypeScript?

Answer (score 2):

Because TypeScript is structurally typed, the only reason you would add an `implements` statement would be to get a warning that you have forgotten to implement a method from the interface.

If you don't want to be warned about this, you can simply ommit the `implements State` annotation.

Example... I am using the `Example` interface to ensure that the object passed to my `usesExample` is acceptable... I get type safety throughout, and I don't need to put an abstract implementation of `method` on my abstract class.

I could (optionally) add the `Example` interface to `SubExample` if I wanted to be told if I forgot to add something... but the line using `usesExample` would do this anyhow.

```
interface Example {
    method(): string;
}

abstract class BaseExample {
    abstract foo(): string;
}

class SubExample extends BaseExample {
    foo() {
        return '';
    }

    method() {
        return '';
    }
}

function usesExample(example: Example) {
    return example.method();
}

usesExample(new SubExample());
```